# React/Redux/CSS - Modal placement

Tags: javascript, css, react-redux, z-index

i have a **Card** and a **Modal** component like so

```
class Card extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { showModal: false }
  }

  render() {
    const { showModal } = this.state;
    return (
      {/* Some code */}
      {showModal && <Modal />}
    )
  }
}
```

So, I don't want to render my **Modal** until it is required. Logic.

The **Modal**'s job, in this context, **is to display the full content** of the **Card** component (The **Card** has a fixed height, so I cannot displaying every bit of information in there).

---

Now, at a higher level I have the following:

```
class App extends Component {
  /* Some Code */
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Content /> {/* Our content */}
        <Overlay /> {/* Our all-purpose-overlay (we need it for the Modal) */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

---

The problem is that my **Card** component has the style `position: relative` and the **Modal** component has the a `z-index` and the style `position: absolute`.

> I did some research and I read that nested elements with non-static
>   position will not work the same way regarding the z-index. The z-index will take effect only within the non-static element.

So I cannot make my **Modal** appear above the the **Overlay** component. Furthermore, The Card component has a `overflow:hidden` property. And so, the **Modal** gets cropped.

Here is a simple demonstration.

```js
function toggleModal() {
  var app = document.getElementById("app");
  app.classList.toggle("-modal");
}
```

```css
:root {
  background: #ddd;
}

#app,
#overlay {
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Overlay */

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  
  visibility: hidden;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.-modal #overlay {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

/* Card */

#card {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden; /* Problem */
}

.content {
  padding: 4em 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border:none;
  color:white;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  background: #00abff;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #0c9de4;
}

/* Modal */
#modal {
  width: 300px;
  
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 50px; /* Modal Gets clipped */
  
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color:red;
}

.-modal #modal {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="card">
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <button class="btn" onclick="toggleModal()">Display Modal</button>
    <div id="modal">
      <div class="content">
        <div>Modal</div>
        <div>With same content</div>
        <div>(under the Overlay and also cropped)</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay" onclick="toggleModal()"></div>
</div>
```

---

Question : How should I organize my components so that I do not get this problem?

I thought of having only one **Modal** at top level. Then I simply display it. But I need to render the `children` of the **Card** into the **Modal**.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using React, what I would actually recommend is to use a Portal to render your modal. One thing Portals solve in React are precisely this issue. If you are using a more recent version of React (16+) then [you already have access to portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html).

If you are using an older version of React, that is okay. [You can use an implementation like this (react-portal) instead](https://github.com/tajo/react-portal).

Now you will have your components/markup rendered in a totally separate React tree outside of the context of your containing `<div>` that has `position: relative` on it and you can absolute or fixed position it wherever you need to.

Comment: Wow awesome! I'm missing just a small piece of information : how do I get the **Modal** `reference` down to the **Card** component? The two components are really far appart in the virtual DOM. ...or am I missing something? Thanks a lot!

Comment: [I moved my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801687/react-getting-the-reference-for-a-react-portal)