# React - Correct way of passing a reference to a react-portal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, portal-system

I have a **Card** component that needs to trigger a **Modal** component.

I also have a generic **Overlay** component that I am using to display some content above my application.

Here is my **App** component :

```
class App extends Component {
  /* Some Code */
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="c-app">
        <Content /> {/* Our content */}
        <Overlay /> {/* Our all-purpose-overlay */}
        {/* I want my Modal here */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to use my **Overlay** component with my **Modal** component. To get it done, I need both components on the same level (siblings).

---

And so I did some research on **react-portals** and I found that I can do the following in my **Card** component :

```
class Card extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { showModal: false }
  }

  render() {
    const { showModal } = this.state;
    return (
      {/* Some code */}
      {
        showModal 
          && ReactDOM.createPortal(
            <Modal>{* ... *}</Modal>,
            document.body
          )
      }
    );
  }
}
```

In the example above, I am sending the **Modal** into the **body** element.

---

### Question

How can I get a reference to the **App** component without sending it through the props?

The thing is that the **App** component and the **Card** component are really far apart. It is a little ridiculous to send down the reference of the **App** component through all the children until it reaches a **Card** component.

I could also save it it into the **Redux** Store, but I don't think it is good practice.

How should I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Redux offers functionality for passing refs without saving them explicitly in the store.

You can set the withRef option as true in your connect() call:

```
connect(null, null, null, { withRef: true })(<Your component>);
```

And access the ref by the following method:

```
ref={connectedComponent =>
        this.<Your component>=
        connectedComponent.getWrappedInstance();
```

This medium article may prove helpful. 
https://itnext.io/advanced-react-redux-techniques-how-to-use-refs-on-connected-components-e27b55c06e34
Also were I got the sample code above from.

Comment: Hi @Rowan, this is pretty interesting! I have some trouble understanding something with this approach : how does my **Card** component gets access to the reference of the **App** component? Maybe I'm missing something. As i understand it, this creates a reference that is accessible only by the connected component. So if I connect the **App** component in this way, it will a have a reference to itself. Then I can pass it to the children? How does the **Card** component gets access to this reference ? Thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am in the mountains and service is spotty. I believe something along the lines of `App.getWrappedInstance().refs['selector']`. Though normally I would be exposing a ref from a child to a parent, I think this should work though.